# Did Apple just create a new restricting rule for video autoplay?

Tags: ios, video, autoplay, ios17, macos-sonoma

I have a website developed in Webflow https://www.menghrani.com/, and the info videos in the "Services" section are set to start playing only when scrolled into view. It worked perfectly on Android, Mac, Win and iOS up until the recent update to iOS 17.1 and Mac OS 14.1, now on iOS it shows a play button on top of the video, similarly to how it appears during the power saving mode in iOS. On Mac OS, it works in Chrome but in Safari it also shows a play button. Strangely this happens on the new Mac OS devices, whereas my vintage Macbook Pro 15 doesn't have this issue even with 14.1
Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: This might be because of the "Low Power Mode". When the device is in this mode, videos will not be played automatically.